# How to sort a php foreach loop in an html form

Tags: php

I have a form that allows users to select from a list of cities in  options. I use a foreach() approach to automatically populate the options with all cities in the database, The problem is that I am not sure how to get the results to sort alphabetically.

Here is the code so far without any sorting:

```
 City:
 <select name="city">
 <option value="" selected="selected">Any</option>
 <?php foreach($city_list as $city) : ?>
 <option><?php echo $city; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Sort the PHP array before your code above.  Search on "php sort" for examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: You really don't need to sort on PHP, just specify ORDER BY when you get cities from database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
City:
<select name="city">
<option value="" selected="selected">Any</option>
<?php
sort($city_list);   // <-- The magic
foreach($city_list as $city) : ?>
<option><?php echo $city; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

[sort](http://php.net/sort)

Comment: worked like a charm. I suppose I could have used order by, but I wasn't sure of the syntax given the array ($city_list as $city).

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to sort the result set via the SQL query as Triby suggests.

For example:

> $query = "SELECT city FROM CityTable ORDER BY city ASC";

It's much more efficient and quicker by leveraging the power of database server to do the job.  That's what db servers are built to do.

Comment: I get that. Got to your answer after approving the sort one. This is such a tiny little web page so speed is not an issue, but point taken.

Comment: The sort() function may apply for any array, not just an array from DB, so the sort() answer is the correct for this question